# How to Parsing XML?

Tags: c#, wcf

how to parse this XML.Here, i want to take the name and picture URL..

I am trying this code..

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient();
var friendListData = client.Get("https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=100005000000000&fields=name,picture");
JObject friendListJson = JObject.Parse(friendListData.ToString());                                

string json = Convert.ToString(friendListJson);
XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root");
string xml = doc.InnerXml;
XDocument myXdoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));
var list = from loc in myXdoc.Descendants("root").Elements("100005000000000")
           select new
           {
               //Id = loc.Element("id").Value,
               Name = loc.Element("name").Value,
               url=loc.Element("url").Value,

           };
```

But, getting error is "Name cannot begin with the '1' character, hexadecimal value 0x31."
Please correct it.

```
<root>
    <100005000000000>
        <name>XXX</name>
        <id>100005000000000</id>
        <picture>
            <data>
                <url>http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/000000_100005000000000_1666666666_q.jpg</url>
                <is_silhouette>false</is_silhouette>
            </data>
        </picture>
    </100005000000000>
</root>
```

here is the json

```
{
  "100005000000000": { 
                       "name": "XXXX", 
                       "id": "100005000000000", 
                       "picture": { 
                                    "data": { 
                                              "url": "profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/…;, 
                                              "is_silhouette": false 
                                            } 
                                  } 
                     } 
}
```

Comment: Your XML is invalid, it's not XML. Where did it come from?

Comment: Here, I am converting from Json to XML format

Comment: How are you doing the conversion?  And just out of curiosity, why are you converting from JSON to XML?  Just pull the relevant data out of the JSON.

Comment: Please post the code that you used to convert from JSON to XML as it is likely that this is where your problem lies.

Comment: Yes, I see. The JSon must be invalid or unsuitable, can you post (part of) the Json string?

Comment: @Neil, @Tim : `JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode()`

Comment: {
  "100005000000000": {
    "name": "XXXX",
    "id": "100005000000000",
    "picture": {
      "data": {
        "url": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/000000_100005000000000_1666666666_q.jpg",
        "is_silhouette": false
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: The conversion to XML obviously creates an invalid XML document (tag names may not start with a digit, so `<100005000000000>` is invalid). You have to use a different approach.

Comment: I'm wondering if that is valid JSon, I don't think `100005000000000` is a valid member-name in JavaScript either.